# load word file (.docx) in richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, text, ms-word, richtextbox

I was already able to load a .docx file into my wpf application but it doesn't seem to show up in my richtextbox:

```
if (openFile.ShowDialog() == true)
{
     // Open document 
     string originalfilename = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(openFile.FileName);

     if (openFile.CheckFileExists)
     {
         var document = DocX.Load(originalfilename);
         string contents = document.Text;
         rtfMain.Document = contents; 

         MessageBox.Show("file loaded");
     }
}
```

The contents string variable is not accepted by the richtextbox in wpf. Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (openFile.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            // Open document 
            string originalfilename = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(openFile.FileName);

            if (openFile.CheckFileExists && new[] { ".docx", ".doc", ".txt", ".rtf" }.Contains(Path.GetExtension(originalfilename).ToLower()))
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                object File = originalfilename;
                object nullobject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordobject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                wordobject.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document docs = wordObject.Documents.Open(ref File, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
                docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
                docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
                rtfMain.Document.Paste();
                docs.Close(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
                wordobject.Quit(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);


                MessageBox.Show("file loaded");
            }
        }
```

Comment: It might help to add some context and descriptions here.  Also,  please use the code format button "{ }" when adding code...

Answer (score 0):

That code shouldn't compile, `RichTextBox.Document` is of type `FlowDocument`, and you are assigning it to a `string`.

Maybe you should look for ways to convert a **.docx** file to a `FlowDocument` you can assign to the `RichTextBox`.

There is a popular tool you can use which is called: [Word to XAML](http://wordtoxaml.codeplex.com/)

Another options are:

- [OpenXML + FlowDocument = OpenFlowDocument?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25071/OpenXML-FlowDocument-OpenFlowDocument)
- [Show Word file in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/649064/Show-Word-file-in-WPF)