# Database varbinary(MAX) to RichText Box

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, ckeditor, richtextbox

Here i Saved .Doc files in Database and i used varbinary(MAX) Datatype. Now I want to bind the  varbinary(MAX) field to Richtext box, Here i am used bellow code to  Read binary format data to string type.

```
string Query = "Select Name, ContentType, DocFileText from <TableNAme> where Id=5";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader sqlRead = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
            while (sqlRead.Read())
            {      
           byte[] fileData = ((byte[])sqlRead["DocFileText"]);
            Richtextbox1.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileData);            
              }
```

but the data should be in unreadable format like :

```
PK!0?(r?[Content_Types].xml ?(??T?n?0?W??D?V??????[??0??z??l?I?Q?B? \"%?????????l ?w%?=???^i7+???%?g&??0?A?6?l4??L60#????S ????X??&??V$z?3??3 ??????%p)O5?????5}?:?`?e????V?DFK??)_:?K%?)?l??\?!??U?'?v?7?&j?X??*,??+W^.,???????W????k??D?????X?????>??N!??FZ??&0m??ly??)?q?9??d}???@??????????R??/??s???*&:t??g?????????8Y?O?[??&V0}?X????????>?#??;?F?io.????PK!???N_rels/.rels ?(????JA???a?}7? "???H?w"????w?????? ?P?^????O?????;?<?aY????`G?kxm??PY?[??g G??ino?/"f3??\???T??I S??????????W????Y ig?@??X6_?]7~ f?????ao?.b*lI?r?j)?,l0?%??b? 6?i???D?_???, ? ???|u?Z^t??y??;!Y,}{?C??/h>??PK!??? ?word/_rels/document.xml.rels ?(????J?0?????n????l?????v???$?j?????..??K`?????0??L'????YI?@[????????? D mK?9? ?Ooovo?i?G?i? ?? Q?,e(4:D?G?7??F????.>u?r?[???^x?C???{??s??????_\q4h?J?H?????FRpR"?ya?* ?p???d?x{49z??Dp?? ?kB?Nc)?3Ybx\??r?2?w3?????&?7??Vr&?@??oK??PK!??????2word/document.xml?Y[O?0~????r????BiCH????.???????_?s?84?-a-#??;>??|>N..??P?S.?u???5{l??}???{??5!I??@???Z#sl?}?????M??iuK??B?? ???]????=???O?F??o????ba?)??Nw8,Ht'pn6??P7??p)N?*97?tl???#'L???????se~??;?Y??;???}?K?????v???M??????K???j?>U????+g?^U|?????C N???M?~%????a???????H??m?/?&?M_?i=??????VQN?0?J?@??l??J?|!U??4[]S%??7?$?i7:?bB???Nl??{uH5""3%hA?:?g?????n???:????@??xi%?z_vZ?*U?m??u??2?Jq??'?3?h???1Q?, ??????'??;??g?? ?Ev?????0$??`XmtGr??!?e_?}v??#??????????dT?h+?j-,A?%#???6? ??w?????|UOQ4????E?ga?V???#?????w2?|????????~????WH??X????t?^^???O????????lK?=?K????? ?93?.????????????ev?j??????|?4?y0??e?????=FV ??^?r?Zh9#??_vvsN3?r????????\m?]??1Y n4?X/2?.??`?%O?a????A??l??????N?d???????PK!?????Pword/theme/theme1.xml?YOo?6??w toc'vu????-M?n?i???P?@?I}?????a??m?a[????4?:l???GR??X^?6???>$?????????!)O?^?r?C$?y@?????/?yH*??????)?????????UDb?`}"?q???J?????X^?)I`n?E???p)???li?V[]?1M???G?M?Ge???D?????3Vq%'#q??????$?8??K?????)f?w9:????? x}r?x????w???r?:\TZaG?*?y8I?j?bR??c|X??????I u3KG?nD1?NIB?s??? ??R??u???K>V?.EL+M2?#'?f??i~?V??vl?{u8??z??H? ?*????:?(W???? ~??J??T?e\O*?tHG??HY???}KN??P?*???????T???9/#??A7?qZ??$*c????qU??n??w?N??%??O??i??4=3??P?? ????1?P?m\\9?????????M???2a?D?]?;Yt?\????[x??????]?}Wr??|?]??g-??? eW? ?)6-r??CS?j?? i?d ?D??A???IqbJ#x????6k???#??A?Sh???&??t(Q?%??p%m??&]?caSl=?X???????\P?1?Mh?9?M???V?dDA??aV?B??[??fJ???P|8???A?V^???f ?H??n???-??"??d>?z???n????? ?????>??b???&?????2??v????Ky?????D:????,AGm??\nz??i?????.u??YC?6?OMf??3o?r??$??5?????NH?T[XF64?T,?????M0?E)`#?5?XY?`???;??%?1?U???m;???R>QD????D?cp?U?'??&LE?/p???m????%]?????8fi??r?S4?d7y\?`?J??n??????I?R???3U?~7+?????#??m?q?BiD??????????i*?L6?9??m?Y&?????i???HE??=(K&?N!V??.K?e?LD????{D ????vE???de??N????e?(?MN9??R??6????&3(??a????/D??U?z???)???D????_??k??wXXub?????(?9??8?????????????<4??u?>?p?? ???F????
```

Here i used

```
 Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileData);
            Encoding.Unicode.GetString(fileData);
```

but these are also not working.
How can i read Doc file from database to richtextbox ?

And My Uploaded Code is:

```
 string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        Stream str = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(str);
        Byte[] size = br.ReadBytes((int) str.Length);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connstring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into Gtrans(Name, ContentType, DocFileText) values(@Name, @ContentType, @DocFileText)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", filename);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", "application/word");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocFileText", size);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you read the DataText column (sqlRead["DataText"]) if you haven't selected it?

Comment: Hay Sorry For that ..now I updated my question.Check once.

Comment: Could you provide us the code which stores the. doc into your database?

Comment: Hi @whymatter ..I updated My Question with Inserted Code aslo

Comment: and how do you get `FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream`

Answer (score 0):

Okay there are two problems with your approach.

### Point 1 (If you are using winforms):

If you like to load rtf text into a `RichTextBox` then you have to use the `Rtf` property of the `RichTextBox`. Not the `Text` property. [See this for more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

### Point 2:

You can't open `.doc` in rtf just by passing the .doc string to rtf. `.doc` is something other that rtf.

The good news: it is possible, the bad: you need MS Word.

- Add reference to "Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library" is under the 'Com' section of the references window
- Use this code to convert the `doc` file to `rtf` file

.

```
byte[] yourDocData = null; // in your case (byte[])sqlRead["DocFileText"]

// Save your data as file so word can read it
var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(tmpFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream)) {
    writer.Write(yourDocData);
}

// Convert .doc to .rtf
var newWordFile = (object) tmpFile;
var newRtfFile = (object) Path.GetTempFileName();

var wordObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var docs = wordObject.Documents.Open(ref newWordFile);

docs.SaveAs(ref newRtfFile, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatRTF);

// This is your rtf code
var yourRtfCode = File.ReadAllText(newRtfFile.ToString());

// Dispose
docs.Close();
wordObject.Quit();
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722434/load-word-file-docx-in-richtextbox)

---

### Important

- Use the same `Encoding` for saving / loading your .doc from the database!
- Set the `yourRtfCode` not to the `text`-property of your control but to the property accepting `rtf`-text