# How can I get/set the paragraph line height in a paragraph in WPF RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to get/set the current paragraph (specifically the line-height and line-spacing values) for the current caret position.

I can set the font family thusly:

```
public string SelectionFontFamily
{
    get => GetFormatting(Inline.FontFamilyProperty)?.ToString() ?? "";
    set => SetFormatting(Inline.FontFamilyProperty, value ?? "Times New Roman");
}
private void SetFormatting(DependencyProperty property, object value)
{
    var selection = Rtb.Selection;
    selection.ApplyPropertyValue(property, value);
}
private object GetFormatting(DependencyProperty property)
{
    var range = Rtb.Selection;
    object value = null;
    var pointer = range.Start;
    if (pointer is TextPointer)
    {
        var needsContinue = true;
        DependencyObject element = pointer.Parent as TextElement;
        while (needsContinue && (element is Inline || element is Paragraph || element is TextBlock))
        {
            value = element.GetValue(property);
            needsContinue = ((value is IEnumerable seq)) ? seq.Cast<object>().Count() == 0 : value == null;
            element = element is TextElement ? ((TextElement)element).Parent : null;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

This works as expected. However, I can't figure out how to accomplish the same thing with respect to line-height and line-spacing.

I found an answer that looks promising for the line-height at least [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325075/how-do-i-change-richtextbox-paragraph-spacing)

```
Paragraph p = Rtb.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock as Paragraph;    
p.LineHeight = 10;
```

But I need to apply this to the selected block, not the first block. That might work if I can figure out which paragraph the user has selected with the caret.

Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you found is close. Instead of looking in the document you should be able to look directly at the caret position like this:

```
var paragraph = Rtb.CaretPosition.Paragraph;
```

Comment: Thx for that. I did stumble on that eventually, but it doesn't really solve my problem. The LineHeight value comes back as NaN in spite of the fact I'm loading an RTF document created in Word that specifies a line spacing of double. Not only that, the RTB doesn't display the spacing (i.e., it is rendered as single-spaced). So very confusing.

Comment: Check out the answers to this question and see if they help push you in the right direction. DOCX isn't a 1 to 1 match with a flowdocument. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722434/load-word-file-docx-in-richtextbox

Comment: I'm loading an RTF file. I use Word to create it, but I didn't save it in the .docx format.

Just to make sure it wasn't Word that was the problem, I created a 2nd RTF file. Only this time I used WordPad (it's been years since the last time I opened that app). It only consisted of a single paragraph with double-spacing. Same thing. I can only conclude that the WPF RichTextBox does not support double-spacing.

Thx for the assist, however.